# Unicode JSON in Laravel blade for use in React, generating a JSON.parse problem

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, json, laravel

I have a json object in DB:

```
{
"ui": {},
"title": "Hola mundo 2",
"values": {},
"properties": {},
"description": "descripcion"
}
```

In the Laravel controller, I send the data to the view:

```
$surveyData = Empresa::find($empresa_id)->survey;    
return view('surveys.edit')->with('surveyData', json_encode($surveyData));
```

In the Laravel Blade, I attach the data in a div:

```
<div id="poll" data-survey=@json($surveyData)></div>
```

In React I get the data and save in oldData variable:

```
const oldData = document.querySelector("#poll").dataset.survey
```

The problem is that I'm getting a JSON.parse error in React because that JSON print in the Laravel view DOM in the following unicode format:

```
<div id="poll" data-survey="\u0022{\\\u0022ui\\\u0022: {}, \\\u0022title\\\u0022: \\\u0022Hola mundo 2\\\u0022, \\\u0022values\\\u0022: {}, \\\u0022properties\\\u0022: {}, \\\u0022description\\\u0022: \\\u0022descripcion\\\u0022}\u0022"></div>
```

when I parse that json in React:

```
JSON.parse(oldData)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I really don't know where is the error or what else to do.

Comment: It's telling you the json starts with a `"` (that is \u0022) which is not valid json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to double encode your JSON data:
`json_encode($surveyData)` and then `@json($surveyData)`
Change

```
return view('surveys.edit')->with('surveyData', json_encode($surveyData));
```

to

```
return view('surveys.edit')->with('surveyData', $surveyData);
```

Comment: thanks, now its asking for a "}": Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: I've solved, thank you. I had to do in react: JSON.stringify before parsing